# What's the recipe for a JMX proxy?

Tags: jmx

I don't want to have to pick port numbers for the usual JMX remote management property. Is there a standard methodology for setting up some sort of proxy (e.g., via ssh) to avoid the need to to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Some application servers already have a JMX proxy. In JBoss you can access it with this URL: http://localhost:8080/jmx-console. For more details see this [link](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JMXConsole).

When your application server does not have such a http based way to access JMX, you could create it on your own. Perhaps you can use this nagios plugin ([Jmx4perl](http://labs.consol.de/lang/de/jmx4perl/)) as a starting point. It uses a small java web application, which has to be deployed. After that you cann access the JMX server with http. It also has a special proxy mode, with a dedicated proxy server.